# Since they no longer kill animals for food, what does the replicator use as a template?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, food

Riker said they no longer kill animals and Picard said they didn't exploit them anymore.

If animals weren't raised and killed for food, what did the replicators use as a template?

Comment: Fast food. It has nothing to do with animals either.

Comment: I guess they killed a few animals and cooked them. I don't think they have a ban on killing animals for research purposes (plus IIRC there are restaurants on earth that serve real food, or at least I cannot imagine Joseph Sisko serving sythentic shrimps in his Gumbo).

Comment: I wouldn't overinterpret such a comment. Just because people generally eat synthetic food doesn't mean that there are no Chefs who kill animals to create new food templates.

Comment: Agree with @CodesInChaos.  I remember a TNG episode where O'Brian tells Kako that his mother never used a replicator, she cooked food herself.  Kako was astonished and said 'She handled real meat ?'.  O'Brian says 'yes'.

Comment: These comments are all correct.    And I'd further add, for those who insist on really parsing words:  "no longer kill animals for food" doesn't necessarily mean they don't very occasionally kill an animal to make a replicator template.

Comment: DS9 Papa Sisko is post-Gene scripts. The discrepancy is easily explained

Comment: Also note that while a 3D print can be constructed from a scan, there is opportunity to edit the model.  Most models are probably enhanced by nutritionists and what not.

Comment: @Eran Maybe take a break from ST and do [these](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jedi+-star-wars)?

Comment: @Mithrandir I'm done with editing for a while.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Speculation based on logical reasoning: He said "no longer". Presumably when replicator technology was developed, they still had ample opportunities to scan and store a real steak, to be replicated ad infinitum.

Comment: I also consider this the logical conclusion. The Federation stopped domesticating animals *after* the replicator technology became able to substitute animal products, because real animals were no longer required. The replicator template for steak might be based on the beef of a cow which died centuries ago.

Comment: That had better have been one good steak, if it was going to become the steak that was eaten by everyone for the next three hundred years.

Comment: It makes me wonder if anyone really knew if something tasted *just like chicken.*

Comment: I feel this jump is too much.  As I pointed out above, "no longer kill animals for food" doesn't necessarily mean they don't very occasionally kill an animal to make a replicator template.   Furthermore, you only need to find an occasional animal killed by accident or a predator to slice up for meat and be prepared by the superchef of the era to make new templates without the animal having been "killed for food".

Comment: mmm...infinite steak.